Binding checkbox to model and not return checked states in ASP.NET MVC
When binding checkboxes in a form to a list of models is it possible to return the List<Model> instead of merely the string[] of IDs of the checked boxes?
Ideally I would like to receive the List<Result> after form submission to simply update the previously created entries. Is this a feasible option?
Controller:
public IActionResult Quiz()
{
    //var test = _context2.Questions.Include(test => test.MultipleChoices);;
    //var allQuestions = _context2.Questions.Include(allQuestions => allQuestions.MultipleChoices).ToList();

    var allQuestions = _context2.Questions.Include(allQuestions => allQuestions.Answers).ThenInclude(answers => answers.MultipleChoices).ToList();
    List<Result> allResults = new List<Result>();

    _context2.Results.ExecuteDelete();

    foreach (Question question in allQuestions)
    {
        foreach (Answer answer in question.Answers)
        {
            if (answer.AnswerType.Equals("MultipleChoice"))
            {
                foreach (MultipleChoice multipleChoiceToAdd in answer.MultipleChoices)
                {
                    _context2.Results.Add(createResultToAdd(question, answer));
                    allResults.Add(createResultToAdd(question, answer));
                }
            }
            else if (answer.AnswerType.Equals("TextAnswer"))
            {
                _context2.Results.Add(createResultToAdd(question, answer));
                allResults.Add(createResultToAdd(question, answer));
            }
        }
    }

    _context2.SaveChanges();

    allResults = _context2.Results
                          .Include(allResults2 => allResults2.Question)
                          .Include(allResults2 => allResults2.Answer)
                          .ThenInclude(answer => answer.MultipleChoices)
                          .Include(allResults2 => allResults2.Answer)
                          .ThenInclude(answer => answer.TextAnswers).ToList();

    return View(allResults);
}

private Result createResultToAdd(Question question, Answer answerTemplate)
{
    Result resultToAdd = new Result();
    resultToAdd.QuestionId = question.QuestionId;
    resultToAdd.AnswerId = answerTemplate.AnswerId;
    resultToAdd.CheckedResult = true;

    return resultToAdd;
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult StoreResult(string[] result) //List<Result> results
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

View:
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Quiz";
}
@model List<Result>
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Quiz</h1>
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="StoreResult" method="post">
        @{
            foreach (var QuestionID in Model.OrderBy(m => m.QuestionId).GroupBy(m => m.QuestionId))
            {
                
                var question = @Model.Where(m => m.QuestionId == QuestionID.Key).Select(m => m.Question).First();

                <div class="container-fluid" style="background: #d7f6c8 ;">
                    @{
                        <h2>@question.QuestionText</h2>
                        if (question.ImageAttachment != null)
                        {
                            <img src=@question.ImageAttachment style="width:5em;" alt="Sample Photo" />
                        }

                        var checkBoxIndices = @Model.Where(m => m.QuestionId == QuestionID.Key).Select(m => Model.IndexOf(m)).ToList();
                        var result2 = Model.Where(m => m.QuestionId == QuestionID.Key).ToList();


                        <table class="table">
                            <tbody>
                                @{
                                    if (question.QuestionType.Equals("MultipleChoice"))
                                    {
                                        //foreach (var answer in Model.Where(m => m.QuestionId == QuestionID.Key).ToList())
                                        foreach (int modelAnswerIndex in checkBoxIndices)
                                        {
                                            
                                            if (Model[modelAnswerIndex].Answer.AnswerType.Equals("MultipleChoice"))
                                            {
                                                var mcqAnswer = Model[modelAnswerIndex].Answer.MultipleChoices.FirstOrDefault();
                                                if (Model[modelAnswerIndex].Question.SingleSelect)
                                                {
                                                <td>
                                                        @if (Model[modelAnswerIndex].Answer.MultipleChoices.First().ImageAttachment == null)
                                                        {
                                                            @Model[modelAnswerIndex].Answer.AnswerText  @*Option Text *@
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            @Model[modelAnswerIndex].Answer.AnswerText  @*Option Text *@
                                                        <img src=@mcqAnswer.ImageAttachment style="width:5em;" alt="Sample Photo" />
                                                        }
                                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Result" value="@Model[modelAnswerIndex].ResultId" checked="@Model[modelAnswerIndex].CheckedResult"> @*Radio Button *@
                                                </td>
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                <td>
                                                        @if (mcqAnswer.ImageAttachment == null)
                                                        {
                                                            @Model[modelAnswerIndex].Answer.AnswerText  @*Option Text *@
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                                @Model[modelAnswerIndex].Answer.AnswerText  @*Option Text *@
                                                        <img src=@mcqAnswer.ImageAttachment style="width:5em;" alt="Sample Photo" />
                                                        }


                                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="Result" value="@Model[modelAnswerIndex].ResultId" checked="@Model[modelAnswerIndex].CheckedResult">
                                                </td>
                                                }
                                                // }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    }
                </div>
            }
        }
        <button class="btn btn-primary mt-4"  type="submit">Abgabe</button>
    </form>
</div>


In desktop land, and for Maui (Android, IOS, Windows), then most of the time, you can get back the selected  item as a valid object. However, in web land, due to the "state-less" nature of how the web works, then the objects used to fill such tables or lists are not persisted, since we really only have the browser markup to store such information. So, you have to take the list of returned "id"'s, and re query the data into a list of objects. WebForms allowed server side persisting of database PK id's, and thus you never had to expose database PK id's to the client side (a huge security risk)

So, no, the objects are not persisted. You have to query based on a returned list of PK values.

Is this a feasible option? No and it's not worth of trying. Just accept that you get list of strings back and build your code around this. I also recomment moving this Model.Where from view to the controller, keep your views as focused on rendering as possible rather than making your views do some extra processing.
